# How to split the background color of UIView in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibackgroundcolor

I want to differentiate the background color in my app screen horizontally.

I have tried this, it's going nowhere.

```swift
var halfView1 = backgroundView.frame.width/2
backgroundView.backgroundColor.halfView1 = UIColor.black
```

backgroundView is an outlet from View object on storyboard

For example, half of the screen is blue and another half of the screen is red.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Mars only the code that is shown above, im so blank

Comment: How about to set the Gradient ? [**Check this**](https://github.com/matvdg/Gradient-View).

Comment: @Mardydu Check my updated answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create a custom UIView class and override `draw rect` method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(HorizontalView(frame: self.view.bounds))
    }
}
class HorizontalView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        let topRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.size.width/2, height: rect.size.height)
        UIColor.red.set()
        guard let topContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        topContext.fill(topRect)

        let bottomRect = CGRect(x: rect.size.width/2, y: 0, width: rect.size.width/2, height: rect.size.height)
        UIColor.green.set()
        guard let bottomContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        bottomContext.fill(bottomRect)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you use a custom UIView and override the draw function, here's a Playground example :

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class CustomView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        let bottomRect = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x, y: rect.height / 2),
            size: CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height / 2)
        )
        UIColor.red.set()
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        context.fill(bottomRect)
    }
}

let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: _"I want to differentiate the background color in my app screen horizontally."_ You are splitting it vertically